# MongoDB : Find duplicate when field type is not the same

Tags: mongodb, casting, duplicates, mongodb-query

how can I detecte duplication even if the fields type are not the same ?

```
{id : 1 , price : 5}
{id : 2 , price : "6"}
{id : 3 , price : "5"}
```

so duplicates are

```
{id : 1 , price : 5}
{id : 3 , price : "5"}
```

Comment: Why you inserted `price` in number and string format, better way to insert in number or string to avoid feature processing. If you know that in advance `price` will be number or string then you can query accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$substr` to do the conversion to String going from index 0 to -1 (rest of the string). :

```
db.duplicates.aggregate(
    [{
        "$project": {
            id: 1,
            price: { $substr: ["$price", 0, -1] }
        }
    }, {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$price",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "item": { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "_id": { "$ne": null },
            "count": { "$gt": 1 }
        }
    }]
)
```

The rest of the aggregation `$group` by `$price` to count the number of occurences and match items that have a count > 1 (duplicates). In `item`, you have the initial items that are duplicates :

```
{ "_id" : "5", "count" : 2, "item" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("58616dc177b68a6c54252bc8"), "id" : 1, "price" : "5" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("58616dc177b68a6c54252bca"), "id" : 3, "price" : "5" } ] }
```

To count the number of distinct **fields** duplicated, add :

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "totalCount": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can i use count() on it ?
i tried with not success .... how can i found how many duplicates i have ?

Comment: I've updated my post with a count of distinct fields duplicated (for you example it will give 1 because there is only "5" which is duplicated